# Question on Pauli matrices completeness relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, matrix-elements

In the [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Completeness_relation_2) on Wikipedia, it says that if

$$2 M_{\alpha \beta} = \delta_{\alpha \beta} M_{\gamma\gamma} + \sum_k \sigma^k_{\alpha \beta} \sigma^k_{\gamma \delta} M_{\delta \gamma}$$

for any matrix $M$ then it follows that

$$ \sum_k \sigma^k_{\alpha \beta} \sigma^k_{\gamma \delta} = 2 \delta_{\alpha \delta} \delta_{\beta \gamma} - \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta_{ \gamma \delta} $$

but I do not see how one goes from the first to the second equation.

Comment: And if you really mean *from* the first equation *to* the second equation, move the first term on the right side of the first equation over to the left and then add in the appropriate sums.

Comment: @Ghoster I am trying to arrive to the second equation from the first equation. I do not want to use knowledge of the second equation to get to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k} \sigma^{k}_{\alpha \beta} \sigma^{k}_{\gamma \delta} M_{\delta \gamma} = 2 M_{\alpha \beta} - \delta_{\alpha \beta} M_{\gamma \gamma}$$

Using the repeated indices convention, by now:

But $$M_{\alpha \beta} = M_{\delta \gamma} \delta^{\delta}_{ \alpha} \delta^{\gamma}_{\beta}$$

And $$ M_{\gamma \gamma} = M_{\delta \gamma} \delta^{\delta}_{ \gamma}$$

On the first equation, gives

$$\sum_{k} \sigma^{k}_{\alpha \beta} \sigma^{k}_{\gamma \delta} M_{\delta \gamma} = 2  M_{\delta \gamma} \delta^{\delta}_{ \alpha} \delta^{\gamma}_{\beta} - \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta^{\delta}_{ \gamma} M_{\delta \gamma} $$

So

$$\bigg(\sum_{k} \sigma^{k}_{\alpha \beta} \sigma^{k}_{\gamma \delta} - 2  \delta^{\delta}_{ \alpha} \delta^{\gamma}_{\beta} + \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta^{\delta}_{ \gamma} \bigg)M_{\delta \gamma} = 0$$

To this expression be valid for any generic matrix $M$, the expression among the parenthesis need to be zero